# Step response of the LTI system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Calculate the step response $g(t)$ of the LTI system described by the following differential equation: $$2\ddot{y}(t)+\dot{y}(t)-y(t)=6\ddot{u}(t)$$

Is the problem, I worked with y'' and y' before but in this problem y(0) and y'(0) aren't given also what is u''. Im lost, I would be glad if you can help me! I have this hint : G(s) = H(s)/s but don't know how to use it.

Comment: The hint is pointing you at using the [Laplace transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform).

Comment: @JohnHabert yes I will use the Laplace Transform but there is no y(0) and y'(0), besides how am I going to process u''?

Comment: Since it is LTI, you could assume $y(0)=0$. The $y'(0)$ and what $u(t)$ are stump me as well. There is either something missing or miscopied from the problem. Any other context to the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are required to solve this using Transfer function. As it stated [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_function) transfer function is defined when all initial conditions are zero. Hence, you can assume that $\dot{y}(0)=y(0)=\dot{u}(0)=u(0)=0$. You need to calculate the Laplace transform of both sides and then find $H(s) = Y(s)/U(s)$. Since the Laplace transform of the unit step function is $1/s$, you can find unit step response by calculating reverse Laplace transform of $G(s)=H(s)/s$, which is done by using tables generally.

Note: $\ddot{u}$ is the second derivative of the input function, nothing special.

Comment: this means I can treat u'' also like y'' which means I can do 6s(u'(t))-u'(0) and then 6s(su(t)-u(0))-u'(0) ? If this is correct I can handle from this moment onwards :)

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Saolasin yegenim!